# Where can I find facebook SDK 4.0+ for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm building an app on Parse iOS SDK 1.9.1 and Facebook iOS SDK 4.8.1 However, it is not officially compatible and I'm having issues compiling the darn thing. http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html says that it is compatible with 4.0+ facebook iOS SDK. Great, I'll just build on 4.0. However, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/deprecated does not have the link to download the dangnabit (but they do for android... great). Anyone have a solution to this problem / a link to iOS 4.0 SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Realize that you can just include in the podfile and get the version you need
For me, I needed this

```
pod 'Parse'
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '4.0.1'
```